# Why does Swift auto delete the last closure parameter name?

Tags: swift

For example:

```
private func test1(closure1: () -> Void, closure2: () -> Void) {

}
```

when called:

```
self.test1(closure1: {

}) {

}
```

**The `closure2` had been deleted.**

---

Also:

```
private func test2(closure1: () -> Void, closure2: () -> Void, closure3: () -> Void) {

}
```

when called:

```
self.test2(closure1: {

}, closure2: {

}) {

}
```

**The `closure3` had been deleted.**

---

I can't understand why Apple designed it like this.

It makes the code less clear.

Comment: Please read the section [Trailing Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102) in the Language Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a kind of convention in the industry - displaying the last closure in a function as a [trailing closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102). There is nothing but syntactic sugar in it. However, it's worth mentioning that you can write it either way, and I personally find it useful to distinguish closures when a method has multiple closure arguments:

```
self.test1(closure1: {
    ...
}, closure2: {
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.2 and below

This is (was) a convention that reads like you are implementing a function (or an object!):

```
Button("Press me") {
    /* Do this block */
}
```

As you can see, calling the function is similar to implementing one.

(Name), (Attributes), (Behaviors).

More information [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)

---

## Swift 5.3

Since Swift 5.3, labels are included:

```
Button("Press me") 
action: { /* Do this block */ }
```

So you can have multiple trailing closures as well:

```
Button {
    /* Do this block */
}

label: {
    Image(systemName: "gear") // Custom button
}
```